# API Get Comments

Tags: jquery, json, git, github

I need to pull the commit comments and their description to the front end of a website.

Here's the repository: `https://github.com/shannonhochkins/SassyGrids`

And here's what I've tried:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/shannonhochkins/SassyGrids/comments', function (data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        items.push(key + ': ' + val);
    });


    log(items);
    console.log(items);
});
```

As you can see the object is empty... I don't really know where else to go from here, can anyone help?

Comment: because https://api.github.com/repos/shannonhochkins/SassyGrids/comments returns nothing:)

Comment: But I have committs, and these commits have comments? What have I done wrong? :(

Comment: I cannot see any comments under these commits: https://github.com/shannonhochkins/SassyGrids/commits/master

Comment: Arent the commit titles what I'm referring to as comments?

Comment: it seems I should be able to get it using `api.github.com/repos/shannonhochkins/SassyGrids/commits` thankyou for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused here and thought that the comments were actually commits, so a small change to my get request and I was able to collect the propper information!

http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/mjbpj/

```
$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/shannonhochkins/SassyGrids/commits', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

That's it!